# Logstash: GROK causing `thread watchdog timeout`

Tags: logging, logstash, log-shipping

I'm trying to setup logstash to parse and ship logs to another server. Almost every time GROK fails to parse the logs, it causes the following error:

```
{:timestamp=>"2013-07-08T02:20:07.390000-0400",
:message=>"thread watchdog timeout",
:thread=>#<Thread:0x133b92c run>,
:backtrace=>["file:/opt/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/filterworker.rb:46:in `backtrace'",
"file:/opt/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/filterworker.rb:46:in `run'",
"file:/opt/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/agent.rb:785:in `each'",
"file:/opt/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/agent.rb:785:in `run_filter'",
"file:/opt/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/agent.rb:492:in `run_with_config'"],
:thread_watchdog=>2013-07-08 02:19:57 -0400,
:age=>10.006,
:cutoff=>10,
:state=>{:event=>#<LogStash::Event:0xa02ea9 @data={"@source"=>"file://clstaging12//home/xyz/xyz.com/apps/logs/mailerjob_log_2013_07_04.txt",
"@tags"=>[],
"@fields"=>{},
"@timestamp"=>"2013-07-08T06:19:50.114Z",
"@source_host"=>"clstaging12",
"@source_path"=>"//home/xyz/xyz.com/apps/logs/mailerjob_log_2013_07_04.txt",
"@message"=>"PID:31730 2013-07-04T13:59:03-05:00 DEBUG :[property_listing_contact.php] Inside getBrokersContactInfoReceivedUserCount of the PropertyListing",
"@type"=>"zend_log"},
@cancelled=false>,
:filter=><LogStash::Filters::Grok type=>"zend_log",
patterns_dir=>["/home/xyz/xyz.com/conf/patterns"],
pattern=>["%{ZEND_LOG}"],
match=>{"@message"=>["%{ZEND_LOG}"]},
tag_on_failure=>["_grokparsefailure"]>},
:level=>:fatal}
```

The pattern ZEND_LOG is :

```
ZEND_LOG_SIGNATURE (?:IP\:(?<clientip>(?:\%ip\%|%{IP})) )?PID\:%{NUMBER:pid}
ZEND_CONTEXT [^\]]+
ZEND_LOG %{ZEND_LOG_SIGNATURE} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:level} \:\[%{ZEND_CONTEXT:context}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

This causes the logstash agent to crash every few minutes, making it almost unusable.
I have looked at many existing bugs filed on JIRA without any luck. Here are a few links:

https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-508

https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-525

https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-765

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to solve this issue completely but after further investigations I found that the error occurs when GROK is not able to match with the entire line i.e. it's still waiting for more input.

This may be entirely because the logs that I'm trying to parse are multiline and I've used a greedy regex. I fixed this by making my regex more strongly typed.